# How set a default Value with EAV AddAttribute

Tags: magento, select, attributes, entity-attribute-value

I want to set up an new attribute-set to my products in magento. This attribute should be  type of selection from some options.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'reserve', array(
    'backend_label'     => 'Attribute Reserve',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'input'             => 'select',
    #'backend'          => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => '',
    #'default'          => 1,
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'option' => array(
        'value' => array( 
            'optionone' => array( 'O' ),
            'optiontwo' => array( 'P' ),
            'optionthree' => array( 'Kein Angabe' ),
        )
    ),
));
```

How can I set `optionthree` to default value?

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. My solution:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'reserve', array(
    'backend_label'     => 'Attribute Reserve',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'input'             => 'select',
   #'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,

    'option' => array(
        'value' => array( 
            'optionone'   => array( 'O' ),
            'optiontwo'   => array( 'P' ),
            'optionthree' => array( 'Kein Angabe' ),
        )
    ),
));
```

Notice the different type (`int` instead of `varchar`) and source (`eav/entity_attribute_source_table`). This is the way Magento represents typical select attributes. Now you can set the default value like this:

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
     ->load($installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'reserve'));
 $model
     ->setDefaultValue($model->getSource()->getOptionId('Keine Angabe'))
     ->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use this script:-

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'reserve', array(
    'backend_label'     => 'Attribute Reserve',
    'type'              => 'varchar',
    'input'             => 'select',
    #'backend'          => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,

    'option' => array(
        'value' => array( 
            'optionone'   => array( 'O' ),
            'optiontwo'   => array( 'P' ),
            'optionthree' => array( 'Kein Angabe' ),
        )
    ),
    /**
     * This will set the default values,
     * as "array" data type is being used to set proper default value
     */
    'default' => array(
        'optionthree'
    ),
));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @koenig - Have you deleted your module unique group code from this database table "`core_resource`"? If that unique group code exists in the database, your installation script will not get called.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to Catalog >Manage Attributes to create new attribute and manage attribue stes to create new attribute set.[image]

Please check the screenshot

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wanto to use an installscript to get the attributes.